# Change Default Action of IFRAME Hyperlink Clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-search, new-window

I'm using Google search in a page, and it shows up in an IFRAME. However, when you click on a link in the search, it's leaving my site and redirecting to that other site. Is there a way to intercept that call with jQuery and make it open that link in a new window, instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to security reasons, what you can do with an iframe is very limited (In cases where you frame another domain).

The way this is implemented varies a bit from browser to browsers but most browsers won't let you manipulate the data in the iframe.

To my knowledge this isn't possible, assuming you are refering to an implementation of  http://www.google.com/cse/